# how to show a String variable with color in alertDialog.setMessage() in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, fromhtml

I want my alertDialog look like this
[image]

My API is 26, and this is my code so far

```
alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Are you sure"+"\n"+"\n"+"<font color='#00bfff'><br><br><b>Est. Total Cost : $ 9.00 </b></font>",Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
```

As you can see I just put 9.00 directly in the String.
Right now, I want to make 9.00 a string variable called estCost, which can be changed based on the calculation in my code.

How can I display the "string variable with the color" estCost in the alertDialog.setMessage() ?

I have tried following code

```
String estCost = calculate(10)  //calculate method will return a double in string.
alertDialog.setTitle("Warning");
alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Are you sure"+"\n"+"\n"+"<font color='#00bfff'><br><br><b>Est. Total Cost : $ <var> estCost </var></b></font>",Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me ! Thanks.

Comment: `<var>"+ estCost+" </var>`

Comment: Dope !!!!!! 
I save my day bro ~
I have searched it on the Internet.
You just killed it for real quick ~ Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concat the value using concatenation operator "+"

```
alertDialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("Are you sure"+"\n"+"\n"+"<font color='#00bfff'><br><br><b>Est. Total Cost : $ <var>"+ estCost+" </var></b></font>",Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spannable text

```
Spannable myText = new SpannableString("are u sure.....");        
myText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),7,10,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
alertDialog.setMessage(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat the font so use + before the font tag and after the font tag that's all.